# In which direction does tension act in a string connecting two different masses and why?

Tags: forces

Imagine two blocks of masses M1 and M2 attached by a massless string. If a force F is applied in the horizontal direction to one of the blocks, then what is the direction of the tension acting on the string?

Answer (score 1):

Short version: An ideal, massless string does not exert any force at all except when it is stretched taut, and then the force with which it pulls on the object at either end of the string can only be directed toward the opposite end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question because it focuses attention on concepts that are fuzzy and not clearly understood.  It's an opportunity to clarify and learn something that generalizes to just about all of Newtonian mechanics.

I'll assume that the force on the block is in the direction that will increase the tension on the block.  You might think that's obvious because a force in the other direction will slacken the string.  But what if the string is under tension to begin with?  Then the applied force can be in either direction.

For any mechanics problem you first have to define your system.  You define it (implicitly) as the string.   Next you need to identify the forces on the string.  Look for contact forces and non-contact forces (e.g. gravity).   There are only two points of contact:  the "left" end and the "right" end.  Ignore gravity.  There are only two forces on the string, one due to the contact with M1, the other with M2.   Each one of these is a tension force that pulls on the string.  A string can't push or be pushed.

A full analysis of this has to take into account the dynamics of the two masses: the forces on them, and their acceleration.  One mass has one force, that due to the string. The other has two forces, one from the string the other the applied force.

A complete analysis of this problem is *very educational*.  I recommend that you do that.  Free body diagrams and Newton's second law for each of the three objects, plus the constraint that they all have the same acceleration because they are attached to each other.

I'll leave that to you with the recommendation that you really do it.  But we don't need the full analysis to answer your question.  Consider the string.  The force on the left side is due to the left block.  The force of tension there is to the left.  The force on the right end is due to the right block. The force of tension is to the right.

Your question is "what is the direction of the tension acting on the string?"  On the left it's to the left.  On the right it's to the right.  So the question as you wrote it is fuzzy.   You might mean "What is the direction of the net force on the string due to the tension forces on the ends?"  If that's the question, you didn't phrase it clearly enough.  And I think you might be able to figure out the direction of the net force on the string without my help ... but let me know if I'm wrong about that.